# Inline editing of image in Angularjs X-editable

Tags: angularjs, x-editable, edit-in-place, inplace-editing

I have many fields in my profile page. I am making my profile page inline editable with Angularjs X-editable. I am making progress using guide http://vitalets.github.io/angular-xeditable/

With this I made all the fields editable except the image field. I have an image i.e. profile pic and I want it to be in place editable [clicking on the edit icon near by the image, the image should change into the image upload widget and after upload image, it should again change back to the show the new image].

Is X-editable having feature of in place editing the image field ?
Or is there any other alternative ?